# avoid org-preview-latex to open a new window

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

I use emacs in frame-only mode and org to typeset latex equations and technical writing.

Since it is hard to see and understand the latex equations in their raw format, I use a package called `org-fragtog` which just calls the function `org-latex-preview` to convert the latex code to an image, and insert it in the current buffer.

The problem is, every time a new equation is inserted for the first time, `org-latex-preview` calls `dvipng` which opens a new window with the message:

```
"This is dvipng 1.16 Copyright 2002-2015, 2019 Jan-Ake Larsson [1] ".
```

Is there a way to suppress this window to open in the first place, or to make it open only when there is an error?

When you are creating lots of equations in a row this gets in the way and stops the flow.

#### Update

While not knowing a lot of elisp, I could craft the function below. The only problem is it is not being called after `org-latex-preview` is executed. Anyone know why?

```
(defun kill-latex-preview-window ()
  (interactive
  (let ((buffer "*Org Preview LaTeX Output*"))
    (if (get-buffer buffer)
        (progn
        (delete-frame (select-frame-by-name buffer))
        (kill-buffer buffer)
        )
    )
  )
  )
)

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'kill-latex-preview-window )
```

Comment: I think you mean a new window, not buffer. I don't think you can inhibit the buffer creation, but maybe you can dismiss the window.

Comment: Hi Muihlinn! Thanks, in fact on second look what I am trying to delete is a frame with a lone window. I tried adding a hook to `post-command-hook` with `delete-window` but I am getting the error: `Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window`. Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: I don't get a new window at all. Can you reproduce this with `emacs -q`? If you cannot, then something in your init file is doing this. Alternatively, you might try to install `imagemagick` and do `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'imagemagick)` and see if that behaves any better.

Comment: I don't use embebbed latex as much to feel such things like an annoyance. Anyhoo I guess that you can pass `-q` to `dvips` to silence it, customizing `org-preview-latex-process-alist`. It's just a wild guess, I don't know if silencing it will have the desired effect.

Comment: Hi @NickD, what is creating the new window is the frames-only mode. It is important for me since I use a tilling window manager, so no reason to split windows in Emacs. If I disable it, the problem goes away. @Muihlinn, I update my post with a function is almost correct. I just need to figure out how to call it with a hook after the `org-latex-preview` execution.

Comment: `bury-buffer` probably will work better than constantly opening/killing buffers. You could use `after` advice to run your code if there is no suitable place to hook it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped.

I contacted the package author which corrected the bug.

The solution is detailed on commit [67de558](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/frames-only-mode/commit/67de5585b96b4e50eaa9f26a363fecc4bd5b33bb) and issue [32](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/frames-only-mode/issues/32).

It basically added the function `org-compile-file` to the list of functions that are blacklisted in `frames-only-mode` in the function `frames-only-mode-use-window-functions`. This way, every time the function is called it only opens a window, and not a frame.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest thing to do is to define your own preview function that locally redefines the function that pops up the buffer so that it does nothing, then redo the key binding so that it calls your function instead:

```
(defun my-org-latex-preview ()
  (interactive)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'display-message-or-buffer) (lambda (msg) nil)))
    (org-latex-preview)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x C-l" 'my-org-latex-preview)
```

Since it's a local redefinition it is unlikely to cause any problems, except in the case where you really want to see that buffer (e.g. in case of errors), but then you can switch to it manually: the buffer is still around, it is just not popped up.

I see also that you opened an [issue](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/frames-only-mode/issues/32) which was a good thing to do: at the very least, they should know about the problem, but there may be a less hackish solution too (or they might implement one).

Comment: I upvoted, but dont have enough reputation yet for it to appear to you. Thanks again Nick!

Comment: No problem - glad it was fixed!